# Various htaccess redirect methods and why?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, permanent

I have an obsolete url (mydomain.com/page.html) which naturally returns a 404 error.  I want to implement a permanent 301 redirect back to my home page at mydomain.com.  (Apache/Linux server with permission to manually edit htaccess file)

I want to be compliant with Google's requirement to have old pages redirected with a 301.

Three methods work but which one is the best and why?  Pros & cons, if any?

1-  This is what cPanel writes automatically (seems like overkill)...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com" [R=301,L]
```

2- This is what I've used in the past...

```
Redirect permanent /page.html http://www.mydomain.com
```

3- I'm wondering if this is best...

```
Redirect 301 /page.html http://www.mydomain.com
```

Thank-you for your opinions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1 uses mod_rewrite and will be slower. There is no difference between #2 and #3 - both use mod_alias and should be faster than #1.

Comment: From an external point of view, like Google's, they all look the same? Just a 301 redirect, right? Thank-you!

Comment: @Sparky672 Yes, all 3 look the same!